# I can't see value in select tag in HTML using Jinja2 for loop

Tags: html, python-3.x, jinja2

I am trying to make a select tag containing values from database.

I try using this

```
<form action="/sell" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="symbol" size=1>
                    {% for item in symbol_port %}
                    <option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
```

I am trying to get item in HTML show the value from my database to allow users to select.

Here's my database query coded in Python

```
symbol_port = db.execute("SELECT symbol FROM portfolio WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])
```

This query of database will show all symbols in symbol column.
I want to show all those symbols in HTML select tag. How can I do this? I have tried several methods, but it doesn't work

**UPDATE!!!**

**THIS IS THE VALUES I WANT TO SEE IN HTML SELECT TAG. IT IS THE VALUES IN SYMBOL COLUMN**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably specify the `item` propriety you are looking for in :

```
<option value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
```

For example `item.symbol` to display symbols in your case.

So it would become :

```
<option value="{{ item.symbol }}">{{ item.symbol }}</option>
```

You can do a `print(symbol_port)` just after your python query to make sure it's the good path.

Comment: After trying print(symbol_port), I got a list of 3 dictionaries like this [{'symbol': 'SD'}, {'symbol': 'NTFL'}, {'symbol': 'MSFT'}]. I think I have to think aobut other new ways to access the value in each dictionary. Your way is still not the solution.

Comment: I can figure out the way. I need to extract values from dictionaries using get() and append all the values into new variable. this makes easier to use in Jinja2

Comment: Considering that `symbol_port` is a list containing dictionaries. You should be able to access to the symbol of each item using `{{ item["symbol"] }}` inside the `for` loop.